# Merging Vector in all possible way

Tags: c++, recursion

Say their is a vector of int. Now we want to merge such that , we  select 2 adjacent element v[I] and v[I+1] ( for each valid I ) and do v[I] = v[I+1] + v[I] . And erase v[I+1] . Keep on doing this until your just left with one element in the vector.(Note I=0 & I=v.size()-1 are also considered as adjacent ). 
so we need to try all such possible combination(i.e which pair we took first and merged matters,if further clarification required please let me know in comment)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int mn =INT_MAX;
void r(vector<int > v, int sum)
{
    if(v.size()==1){if( mn >sum) mn=sum; return ;}

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        sum+=v[i]+v[(i+1)%v.size()];
        v[i]=v[i]+v[(i+1)%v.size()];
        v.erase(v.begin()+(i+1)%v.size());
        r(v,sum);
    }
}
int main()
{
   vector<int> v;//suppose we gave some input to our vector 

   r(v,0);
   cout<<mn;
return 0;

}
```

It would be great if someone modify "r" function, to get desired result. Note mn will store min sum(however this is not of our concern).I am just focused on how to create all possible combination. Help pls :)

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Why would you need to do that anyway? No matter how you merge these elements, the result is still the same, so just pick a favourite way of iterating and sum them up.

Comment: @Quimby it will(i.e sum is different). Take an example say vector is 1 2 3. merging [1 2 3]-> [3,3] &sum=3  -> [6] &sum=9      another way [1 2 3]-> [1,5] &sum=5  -> [6] &sum=11

Answer (score 0):

A given element can only be erased once only.

Therefore consider a permutation, and consider that a value `i` of the permutation corresponds to the element to be erased, i.e. the one of index `i+1`.

Then a permutation corresponds to a possibility, and two different permutations correspond to two different possibilities.

You have to generate all permutations for a brute-force approach.

Many posts here have already analysed the different ways to generate all permutations.

Comment: ya there are many post discussing to generate permutation , but I couldn't find with my required constrain. Moreover "A given element can only be erased once only.", is not true in my case, see the function I haven't passed it by reference.

Comment: If `P` is the permutation. `P[0] = 2` : combine 1 and 2, mark 2 as erased, don't call `erase`. `P[1] = 3`: 3 will be erased, 2 has been marked as erased, so combine 1 and 3, mark 3 as erased. Hope it is clear now

Comment: I agree but , this is not serving our purpose to get all permutation with required constrain. You said "Many posts here have already analysed the different ways to generate all permutations." Can you pls add link which meets my required constrain. I have been browsing since three days!

Comment: I don't understand what you call *required constraint*. You ask to generate all possibilities. Each possibility corresponds to a different permutation